# @Inject Logger (CDI) in EJB with jBoss

Tags: java, jboss, cdi

I'm trying to just inject my Logger into my EJB doing:

```
@Inject
Logger logger;
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.AmbiguousResolutionException: WELD-001318 Cannot resolve an ambiguous dependency between 
[Producer Method [Logger] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[method] @Produces public be.fgov.health.ecad.Resource.createLogger(InjectionPoint)], 
Producer Method [Logger] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[method] @Produces public be.fgov.health.ecad.Resource.createLogger(InjectionPoint)]]
```

I don't really have an idea what this might be? There is, from what I see, nothing wrong with the following class? I don't get why jBoss says there is an Ambiguous dependency..

```
@Dependent
public class Resource {

    @Produces
    public Logger createLogger(final InjectionPoint ip) {
        return Logger.getLogger(ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass());
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe the class `be.fgov.health.ecad.Resource` is provided by different deployed applications.

Comment: Hmm.. Nop. Changed that to an absurd name and still have the error.

Comment: Do you still have the AmbiguousResolutionException but now with two different class names?

Comment: The you should check your class path. If the class `be.fgov.health.ecad.Resource` is still reported twice, even after renaming the class mentioned in your question it look you are deploying not the class you have renamed.

Comment: I've seen similar issues caused by a duplicate `beans.xml`, e.g. both in `WEB-INF` and `META-INF`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to implement this yourself, there is a weld extension for this use case:

[Weld-Logger](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld/weld-logger)

From the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/extensions.html):

Adding logging to your application is now even easier with simple injection of a logger object into any CDI bean. Simply annotate a org.jboss.weld.log.Log type member with the @Logger qualifier annotation and an appropriate logger object will be injected into any instance of the bean.

```
import org.jboss.weld.annotation.Logger;
import org.jboss.weld.log.Log;

public class Checkout {

    private @Inject @Logger Log log;


    public void invoiceItems() {

        ShoppingCart cart;

        ...

        log.debug("Items invoiced for {0}", cart);
    }
 }
```